# Nodemon suddenly stuck in "clean exit - waiting for changes before restart" after adding discord.js command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, nodemon

I'm using node.js + discord.js on vs code, this is also my first time coding, so excuse my ugly formatting etc etc.
Everything is up to date and was running perfectly fine until it just... didn't. It's driving me nuts and none of the solutions that worked for others has worked for me.
I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmKXBVdEV0g&t=3123s) tutorial but deviated from it to personalize my bot.

**Index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const {
    Client,
    Message,
    User,
    ClientUser,
    GuildMember,
    ClientApplication,
    Guild
} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING", "GUILD_PRESENCES"]
});

const prefix = '!';

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('SHOWTIME!!');
    client.user.setStatus('idle');
});

client.on("message", (message) => {// EventEmitter
    if (message.content == "!ping") { // Check if message is "!ping"
        message.channel.send("Pinging ...") // Placeholder for pinging ... 
            .then((msg) => { // Resolve promise
                msg.edit("Pong! " + (Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp)); // Edits message with current timestamp minus timestamp of message
            });
    }
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; {
        if (message.content == "!help") {
            message.channel.send("What can I help you with?")
                .then((message) => {
                    message.react("1️⃣").then(_e => {
                        message.react("2️⃣").then(_e => {
                            message.react("⏹");
                        });
                    });
                });
        }
    }

    client.on("message", (message) => {
        if (message.content == "!ns") {
            (message.react)("");
            message.reply('The next session is scheduled for ...!');
        }
    });

    client.on("message", async (message) => {
        if (message.author.bot) return; {
            if (message.content == "!uptime") {
                (message.react)("✨");
                let days = Math.floor(client.uptime / 86400000);
                let hours = Math.floor(client.uptime / 3600000) % 24;
                let minutes = Math.floor(client.uptime / 60000) % 60;
                let seconds = Math.floor(client.uptime / 1000) % 60;
                message.channel.send((`__I have been online for...__\n${days}d ${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s!`));
            }
        }
    });

    client.login(process.env.token_renren);
});
```

**package.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "renren_v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

**Message that keeps showing up in the terminal:**

```
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node ./src/index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Specifically, Nodemon stopped working after I added **this** specific command:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; {
        if (message.content == "!help") {
            message.channel.send("Hm? What can I help you with?")
                .then((message) => {
                    message.react("1️⃣").then(_e => {
                        message.react("2️⃣").then(_e => {
                            message.react("⏹");
                        });
```

I removed it after it first gave the error to me, but added it back to see if it was the problem. After adding it back, removing it would no longer make nodemon work. I've tried uninstalling, installing it as a project dev, clean installing node, etc and so far nothing has worked.

Comment: That's a nice amount of message event handlers there... You should only have a single `client.on("message")`. And why do you start a block after ` if (message.author.bot) return;`?  Why do you log the client in inside a message handler?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice I placed login in a message handler. Fixed now, thank you very much for the info.

Also, the client.on("message") was because I kept getting a "message declared but never defined" error, and placing that would fix it, but I suppose I should research more bot codes and learn from their coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `clean exit` means your program finishes without any errors. Which is exactly what your program currently does. You define quite a few event listeners, but your bot itself is never started.

As @Zsolt pointed out, you currently log in your discord client inside a message handler. This means, the bot must receive a message before its startet. But since your bot is not logged in, this never happens.

You need to move your login call to the bottom of your script and then it should work:

```js
client.login(process.env.token_renren)
```

---

#### A note on your code structure:

You are defining multiple listeners for one event. While this works, you have no control over the order in which your listeners are called which can lead to unexpected behavior. As @Zsolt pointed out, you usually define **one** `message` listener and then pass on the event to specific functions handling different messages.

You are also changing a lot of `then`s which can make the code very hard to read (this is called [callback hell](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://callbackhell.com/&ved=2ahUKEwi7xMDorI_zAhUmQvEDHXmUCQ4QFnoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0OECniAWPbOPi8Ezo387uT)). You can use `async` functions to avoid this:

```
async function handleMessage(message) {
    if (message.author.bot) return

    if (message.content == "!help") {
        let response = await message.channel.send("What can I help you with?")
        await response.react("1️⃣")
        await response.react("2️⃣")
        await response.react("⏹")
   }
} 

client.on("message",  handleMessage)
```

This makes the code much shallower, making it easier to spot things like the `login` call inside a message handler.

Additionally, most IDEs offer automatic code formatting these days. Unless you are working on a large repository which didn't use this feature, I would highly recommend running that once in a while. I have "format on save" on for my code and got used to it, but that's a personal preference (although it does save time and some employers might even require it). That makes it very easy to spot wrong indentations and weird formating like your `if (message.author.bot) return; {`.

Comment: Moving the login fixed it, thank you!
Seriously, thank you very much for the advice. I did click "format document" on VS code and that's how it put it. Should I get a code extension or just stick with the one built into VS code? As I mentioned, I'm a super noob when it comes to coding so I'm mostly just compiling information from other bot layouts/tutorials/etc, so any extra advice helps a ton.

Comment: I think the built in formatter is perfectly fine if you like it's formatting and work alone. When more people are involved, node based formatters are often used to enforce a coding standard. [EsLint](https://eslint.org/) and [prettier](https://prettier.io/) are popular, both of them have corresponding extensions for all major IDEs. Otherwise, other repositories are always a great resource. As are the documentation examples provided by the library itself.